# R Data.Table After operation column called V1

Tags: r, data.table

I was wondering if I can rename a new generated column in one statement

```
bc <- csv_data[!grepl("post|pads|m|dot|d|cruk|c2", StockCode), sum(as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", UnitPrice))*Quantity),by= c("Country", "CustomerID")]
```

I am actually just doing some calculation and the result is fine so far. Only small mistake is that the new generated column is called V1 and I would like to rename them in the same statement. In SQL I would just use AS, but in R, when I use eg. NewCol:=sum(as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", UnitPrice))*Quantity) the source table gets modified.

Any idea how I can archive this?

Thanks
Stephan

Comment: `list(newcol = sum(as.numeric(...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `.()` operator and assign a new variable `new_var_name`.
Of course, I am assuming you are using the data.table package

```
library(data.table)
setDT(csv_data)
bc <- csv_data[!grepl("post|pads|m|dot|d|cruk|c2", StockCode),
               .(new_var_name = sum(as.numeric(gsub(",", ".", UnitPrice))*Quantity)),
               by= c("Country", "CustomerID")]
```

Comment: perfectly. Thanks a lot

Comment: No need for `<-` after `setDT` since it modifies in place. See `?setDT` and/or `example(setDT)`